# Convert images in nested directories to a single pdf with bookmarks

Tags: windows, pdf, image-conversion

I would like to convert several TIFF files (document scans) into a single, structured PDF. Each page is saved as a single TIFF file, and each chapter has its own directory. Directories can be nested to arbitrary depth.

[image: Example of directory structure]

Is there a way to create a PDF from those images, using the directory names as (hierarchical) bookmarks? In addition to that, it would be even better if I could use a regex to manipulate the bookmark names (e. g., removing the numbered prefixes (`/^[0-9}+_//s` or something like that)).

I have found several solutions for converting a flat folder of images into a PDF file, but no recursive solution.

It doesn't have to be a stand-alone app, a batch/PowerShell file (I'm on Windows) or a Python script would be fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

So, what I ended up doing was:

First, I used `img2pdf` to create a PDF from all the images. At the same time, I listed all the images in a separate text file.

```
import os
import img2pdf

buecher = os.listdir("E:\\")  # each directory under E: contains one book
for buch in buecher:
    with open(f"{buch}.pdf", "wb") as pdf, open(f"{buch}.txt", "w") as contents:
        seiten = []
        seitennr = 0
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(f"E:\\{buch}"):
            for file in files:
                if file.endswith(".tif") or file.endswith(".tiff"):
                    seitennr += 1
                    path = os.path.join(root,file)
                    seiten.append(path)
                    contents.write(str(seitennr) + ": " + path + "\n")
        pdf.write(img2pdf.convert(seiten))
```

Then, I created a tree with all the sections (directory names) and the page numbers where these sections start:

```
def write_tc(file, toc, level=-1, name=""):
    for key, value in toc.items():
        if key == "page":
            file.write("\t"*level + name + "       " + str(value) + "\n")
        else:
            write_tc(file, value, level+1, key)

with open(f"{buch}.txt", "r") as contents:
    tree = {}
    for number, line in enumerate(contents):
        levels = [item for item in line.split("\\")[2:-1]]
        node = tree
        for level in levels:
            node = node.setdefault(level, {})
            if not node:
                node["page"] = number + 1 # pages start from 1

with open(f"{buch}.txt", "w") as toc:
    write_tc(toc, tree)
```

The resulting text files look like this:

```
Inhalt und Einleitung       1
Ulm Straßenverzeichnis       5
    Lit A       5
    Lit B       38
    Lit C       59
    Lit D       88
    Gräben       117
    Vor den Thoren       126
Ulm Branchenverzeichnis       128
Ulm Polizeiverordnungen       134
Ulm Fuhrleute       137
Ulm Personenverzeichnis       141
```

and can be used as input for [HandyOutliner](https://sourceforge.net/projects/handyoutlinerfo/) which merges the TOC into the PDF file generated in the previous step.